# last friday of the month in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Hallo. How can I get the date of last friday of current month with mysql?

Thanks in advance.

edit. Hi Stefan. This is what I've done

```
set @ldom = dayofweek(last_day(curdate()));
select 
case
when @ldom = 7 then last_day(curdate()) - interval 1 day
when @ldom = 6 then last_day(curdate())
when @ldom = 5 then last_day(curdate()) - interval 6 day 
when @ldom = 4 then last_day(curdate()) - interval 5 day 
when @ldom = 3 then last_day(curdate()) - interval 4 day
when @ldom = 2 then last_day(curdate()) - interval 3 day
else last_day(curdate()) - interval 2 day
end as last_friday
```

but I'd like to know if there is a smarter way.

EDIT. I made some test bases on samplebias answer to find last monday,tuesday and so on of a specific month.

These are the correct queries.

```
-- last sunday of month
set @data = '2011-04-01'; 
select str_to_date(last_day(@data) - ((7 + weekday(last_day(@data)) - 6) % 7),"%Y%m%d") -- 2011-04-24

-- last saturday
set @data = '2011-04-01'; 
select str_to_date(last_day(@data) - ((7 + weekday(last_day(@data)) - 5) % 7),"%Y%m%d") -- 2011-04-30

-- last friday
set @data = '2011-04-01'; 
select str_to_date(last_day(@data) - ((7 + weekday(last_day(@data)) - 4) % 7),"%Y%m%d") -- 2011-04-29

-- last thursday
set @data = '2011-04-01'; 
select str_to_date(last_day(@data) - ((7 + weekday(last_day(@data)) - 3) % 7),"%Y%m%d") -- 2011-04-28

-- last wednesday
set @data = '2011-04-01'; 
select str_to_date(last_day(@data) - ((7 + weekday(last_day(@data)) - 2) % 7),"%Y%m%d") -- 2011-04-27

-- last tuesday
set @data = '2011-04-01'; 
select str_to_date(last_day(@data) - ((7 + weekday(last_day(@data)) - 1) % 7),"%Y%m%d") -- 2011-04-26

-- last monday
set @data = '2011-04-01'; 
select str_to_date(last_day(@data) - ((7 + weekday(last_day(@data))) % 7),"%Y%m%d") -- 2011-04-25
```

Hope that it helps someone else. 
Thanks again to samplebias. ;)

Comment: Ok, i wont solve it completely for you but hint: select the region of the month, order it by the date descending, use a where on datepart for weekday and check for friday. Then limit it to 1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a simplified version using just date math:

```
SELECT LAST_DAY(NOW()) - ((7 + WEEKDAY(LAST_DAY(NOW())) - 4) % 7);
```

Depending on how `NOW()` gets evaluated (once or twice per statement), you might want to still wrap this in a function and store the result of `NOW()` into a variable, and then use the variable for the `LAST_DAY(var)` call, to avoid a race condition where the month rolls over between calls to `NOW()`.

Comment: Hallo. Thank you very much. Wonderful solution. I'll study it in order to understand it. I've added str_to_date to get hyphens between date parts. Thanks again :)

Comment: According to MySQL docs, in one statement you can call NOW() many times, the return value is consistent. [NOW() returns a constant time that indicates the time at which the statement began to execute.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now)

Comment: Days of Black Friday in the next 10 years: `SELECT
 (nov1 + INTERVAL _next.next YEAR) day,
 (LAST_DAY((SELECT day)) - INTERVAL ((7 + WEEKDAY(LAST_DAY((SELECT day))) - 4) % 7) DAY) blackFriday
FROM (
 SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-11-01') nov1
) AS _years
CROSS JOIN (
 SELECT 0 next
 UNION SELECT 1
 UNION SELECT 2
 UNION SELECT 3
 UNION SELECT 4
 UNION SELECT 5
 UNION SELECT 6
 UNION SELECT 7
 UNION SELECT 8
 UNION SELECT 9
 UNION SELECT 10
) _next`

Answer (score 1):

```
-- Today is 05 April 2013

-- Get Last Friday from MySQL

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(NOW()) - ((7 + WEEKDAY(LAST_DAY(NOW())) - 4) % 7), '%Y-%m-%d') last_friday;

-- Output

last_friday  
-------------
2013-04-26
```

Comment: This answer is just a formatted version of the existing answer.  Is there anything to add to it?

Comment: @rgettman: Just, added DATE_FORMAT to get output as 2013-04-26